# In a clientside project using npm, Gulp, and Browserify, can I make only Browserified code use `browser: true`?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, browserify

I have a clientside app that is built using Browserify via Gulp. I'd like to use the `package.json` `browser` property to indicate to my Browserified code it should use browser adaptions where applicable. This, however, causes my gulpfile to also use this mode. Is there any way I can make only my Browserified code use the `browser: true` property?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean about the `gulpfile` using `browser` mode? What happens exactly?

Comment: @Ben Having thought about it, I think I have jumped to the wrong conclusion. `browser: true` support is implemented by the CJS bundler, so I don't believe node itself (in which gulp is executed) would acknowledge it.

Essentially, bundling my app with `browser: true` causes a Browserify error `TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object` - but this must be due to one of my frontend dependencies, rather than the bundler itself.